# Replace specific line in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, replace

I want to replace a line, which has the word "truck_placement: " in it, but the problem is that it replaces the line with this word too: "my_truck_placement: ".

My question is, how I can make it so it ONLY replaces that specific word.
I couldn't find anything on the internet to it. Also I'm new to Python.

```
cordget = coordinatesentry.get()



    with open(save_file, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    
    data = re.sub(r"truck_placement: .*\n", r"truck_placement: %s\n" % cordget, data)

    with open(save_file, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your regular expression from `truck_placement: .*\n` to `(?<!_)truck_placement: .*\n`

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kQcxFw/1).